# How to create two variables refering the same nested table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, nested-table

I expected that in the following code variables `x` and `y` refer the same nested table object but expression `y = x` seems to create empty table in `y`. So output is surprisingly **'No: a c'** ( however I expected **'Yes: a b c'**). What should I do in PL/SQL to have `y` referring the same nested table object as `x`.

```
declare
  type str_t is table of varchar(100);
  x str_t := str_t ();
  y str_t ;
begin 

  x.extend;  x(x.last) := 'a';

  y := x;

  y.extend;  y(y.last) := 'b';

  x.extend;  x(x.last) := 'c';

  dbms_output.put_line(case when x=y then 'Yes: ' else 'No: ' end);

  for i in x.first .. x.last
  loop       
     dbms_output.put_line(x(i));      
  end loop;
```

Сan it (passing nested table by reference - not by value) be written in PL/SQL or it's fundamentally impossible? Does any alternatives exist in the language to aviod the problem?

Comment: They are not equal. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL doesn't have references (but in one place we'll see later) so essentially what you're asking is impossible in PL/SQL. I don't see how that can be a problem, though.

In your example `x` and `y` are two different variables that are having the same type (a nested table collection), `x := y` is a variable assigment (deep copy), `x = y` is a [comparison](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00506). See also e.g. [Assigning Values to Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS216).

I guess you've programming background with some other languages and you're trying to apply some other language paradigm here. You also might have an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

One alternative is to use two different index variables to access the collection. That might or might not suit for your case:

```
declare
  type str_list_t is table of varchar2(32767);
  v_foos constant str_list_t := str_list_t('a', 'b', 'c');
  -- have some business logic to get the right indices
  i pls_integer := 1;
  j pls_integer := 3;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(v_foos(i));
  dbms_output.put_line(v_foos(j));
end;
/
```

But please note that changes to collection will invalidate the index variables (that's why I declared a constant collection).

When working with nested tables check also [SQL multiset conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99913) that provide a powerful manipulations.

The only place with reference semantics is [subprogram parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00806) where different parameter modes (`IN`, `OUT` or `IN OUT`) have different semantics (pass-by-value or pass-by-reference). But even there the decision is made by PL/SQL compiler/runtime - programmer has no much control.

Answer (score 0):

> So output is surprisingly 'No: a c' ( however I expected 'Yes: a b c').

Your expectation is wrong. Since the two arrays are having different values.

Let's see step by step:

> x.extend;
>   x(x.last) := 'a';

So, **x** has value **a**.

> y := x;

**x** is copied to **y**, so **y** has value **a**.

> y.extend;
>   y(y.last) := 'b';

Now, **y** has **a** and **b**.

> x.extend;
>   x(x.last) := 'c';

Now, **x** has **a** and **c**.

Finally,

```
X --> a,c
Y --> a,b
```

Let's see what your code shows the output:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2  type str_t
  3  IS
  4    TABLE OF VARCHAR(100);
  5    x str_t := str_t ();
  6    y str_t ;
  7  BEGIN
  8    x.extend;
  9    x(x.last) := 'a';
 10    y         := x;
 11    y.extend;
 12    y(y.last) := 'b';
 13    x.extend;
 14    x(x.LAST) := 'c';
 15    FOR i IN x.first .. x.last
 16    LOOP
 17      dbms_output.put_line('X'||'-'||x(i));
 18    END LOOP;
 19    FOR i IN y.first .. y.last
 20    LOOP
 21      dbms_output.put_line('Y'||'-'||y(i));
 22    END LOOP;
 23  END;
 24  /
X-a
X-c
Y-a
Y-b

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, **X** and **Y** are not equal.

To make them equal, set **Y** = **X**:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2  type str_t
  3  IS
  4    TABLE OF VARCHAR(100);
  5    x str_t := str_t ();
  6    y str_t ;
  7  BEGIN
  8    x.extend;
  9    x(x.LAST) := 'a';
 10    x.extend;
 11    x(x.last) := 'b';
 12    x.extend;
 13    x(x.LAST) := 'c';
 14    y         := x;
 15    dbms_output.put_line(case when x=y then 'Yes: ' else 'No: ' end);
 16    FOR i IN x.first .. x.last
 17    LOOP
 18      dbms_output.put_line('X'||'-'||x(i));
 19    END LOOP;
 20  END;
 21  /
Yes:
X-a
X-b
X-c

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Lalit Kumar, thank you for detailed explanation. But the problem remains. I don't want to make a copy of nested table X, but I want two references to one nested table, so that variables Y and X could equally affect the same table. The question is "can it be written in PL/SQL or it's fundamentally impossible?".

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You are assigning two different values to the respective arrays, so why do you expect them to be same?

Comment: Actually, I expect the only one `respective array`. Its unusual that passing a value of complex type (which an array is) to another variable results making a copy. In other languages (Java, JavaScript, Python etc.) only primitive values (as integers) are being passed by value, but every complex object (arrays, lists etc.) exists as one instance and can be passed by reference only - if we need a copy that object should be explicitly copied.

Comment: Regarding `y := x;` in Oracle, I assure you x is copied to y.

Comment: @DullyFogel Please mark it answered if it has helped you, it would help others as well.